# Executing command on the server side

Tags: sockets, server, client, tcl

While trying to run a server-client based functionality using TCL, i am unable to execute the command tcl commands other than **puts "string"** when the client sends something to execute on the server side (both client and server are tcl based). I tried commands as below on the client:

```
puts $channel {set x 1};flush $channel;
puts $channel {incr x}; flush $channel;
puts $channel {puts $x}; flush $channel;
```

But the last line doesn't show the value of x, it just gives a blank line as an output. On the server side, i am using:

```
if {[catch {eval $line} $result]} {puts $result }
```

Can someone suggest why x is not being evaluated and printed? Also, how does scope is defined for variables sent from client to server or vise versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument of the catch command is supposed to be a variable **name**. You used the **value** of the result variable, which apparently is empty, given that you report that the command produces a blank line as an output.

So you have to at least omit the dollar sign:

```
if {[catch {eval $line} result]} {puts $result}
```

But given that catch will evaluate its second argument, that's a bit convoluted. It can be simplified to:

```
if {[catch $line result]} {puts $result}
```

---

When you handle the socket data inside a proc (that you invoke from e.g. a file event), the scope will be that proc. So every time you will get a (nearly) blank scope. The effects of the earlier commands that ran in a different invocation of the proc will have been lost. That's why the `puts $x` is likely to fail with `can't read "x": no such variable`.

You can run the received commands in the global scope using:

```
if {[catch {uplevel #0 $line} result]} {puts $result}
```

It is likely even better to run them in a separate (safe) interpreter:

```
# In your initialization code (running once):
interp create rje

# In your file event handler:
if {[catch {rje eval $line} result]} {puts $result}
```

When using a safe interpreter, it doesn't automatically have access to the "stdout" channel. You will have to arrange for that as follows:

```
# In your initialization code (running once):
interp create -safe rje
interp share {} stdout rje

# In your file event handler:
if {[catch {rje eval $line} result]} {puts $result}
```

Comment: For people not familiar with old UNIX systems: Each account used to have a directory for "remote job entry", called "rje". That also seemed like an appropriate name for the interpreter in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to increment the value of x now using uplevel.

What is the advantage of safe interpreter? and why is it recommended?

Comment: Using an interpreter completely isolates the environment used for executing the remote commands from your code, so the remote commands won't be able to overwrite your variables and procs. A safe interpreter will make sure that the remote commands can't do anything destructive to your system.